# Is there a way that I (as an admin) can force a message into the Outlook Focused inbox instead of Other?

Tags: office365, exchange-server

We occasionally would like to send out high-importance emails that we would like everyone to read in a timely manner.  For some users these get delivered to their Outlook "Other" inbox rather than the "Focused" one, meaning the contents sometimes get missed.

I imagine this is the Exchange server (or Outlook client) determining somehow based on a variety of indicators that this is not an important message.  e.g. it is sent to all users, someone has their own rule set up to move things to Other, some-other-mechanism

Is there a way we can craft an email or otherwise workaround the issue such that for a specific message we can guarantee it will appear in the "Focused" view?

I've looked at Mail flow rules, but there doesn't seem to be an action that will process the email into a specific place

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with Transport Rules. Basically set up a rule that includes the message that you want to force to focused inbox. Then set the magic header that causes the forcing to happen. All the details are listed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/configure-focused-inbox?view=o365-worldwide#use-the-ui-to-create-a-transport-rule-to-direct-email-messages-to-the-focused-view-for-all-your-users

Comment: That looks a good solution but I don't have the option to set the message header.  I'll see if I can have the permission added to my admin account

Comment: Do you know if X-MS-Exchange-Organization-BypassFocusedInbox can be added to the message before it's sent or does it have to be added through a transport rule?

Comment: transport rule set by an administrator...if this could be sent by the client sending the message then everyone do it which defeats the purpose of the Focused/Other feature.

A gentle reminder to train your users that they can turn off the Focused/Other feature if it doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a header that will force this and prevent a user from moving it to "Other".

It's the [`X-MS-Exchange-Organization-BypassClutter` header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/use-rules-to-bypass-clutter).
Simply apply the header with a mail flow rule and set the value to "true".